# Is there a concept of soul mate in Hinduism?

Tags: scripture, philosophy

I have come across many philosophies in Hinduism with regards to the soul or "atman".
I was just curious if there is any concept of soul mate explained in Hinduism?  Can anyone enlighten?

Comment: I am not sure if I am being off topic here, but there are many examples like Shiva-Shakti, Radha-Krishna etc that come to my mind.

Comment: I think Shiva-Sati is the very first soul mate.

Comment: It seems "[Soul mate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soulmate)" doesn't just highlight lovers, it could be even best friends. Please edit your question if you want to make it more specific.

Comment: Soul mate concept in Hinduism is not what it is understood commonly in new age spirituality. In Hinduism the love for God is the ultimate thing and he is soul mate of everyone. What we consider as soulmates are simply our past lives acquaintances and may have been attached very strongly in one or many of past lives. Some times two or even more than two people may be attached to each other and they take birth at same time to clear-off each other's karmic debts.

Answer (score 5):

God's love is pure, true, eternal, irrelevant of one's own character and only love which doesnot expect anything return from you. Almost all religions convey the same message. Atma in course of life cycles, does punya & pap and based on this karma, one's next birth is decided.

As mentioned [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/3090/65), Runanubandha Rupena Pasu(wealth/possessions) Patni(wife) Sutalayaah(children), the worldly relations are form of debt of ours in the previous births.The only person who can enlighten you is God or Guru who is again a form of God, He is the only soul-mate.

One way for salvation or liberation is to give up everything and take Sanyasa-ashram or the other is Gruhastu-ashram. To enter Gruhastu-ashram one should get married and then should strictly observe the dharmic rituals & practices that are suggested. To perform all such duties, one, if has his spouse with a good harmony & understanding with him, he can perform all such duties with ease and comfort. Spouse is only materialistic-mate of this birth. So, Afaik there is no mention of soul-mate for common man in sanathana dharma except of God/Guru!