Does the concept of soulmate exist as per Hindu scriptures?
Does the concept of soulmate exist as per Hindu scriptures?
As per Vedic astrology, it seems to be possible for someone to have the same person as spouse for many births.
Does this mean that the concept of soulmate exist as per Hindu scriptures?

It's possible due to karma to marry the same person for more than one birth. However, soulmate can be God only. Marriage or Grihastha-ashrama is one of the ashramas to realize the self and supersoul. Otherwise, it will be Kama only. Related: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/3094/34973

I have heard it said in oral traditions from different sadhus to the extent that 2 jivas are bound to rebirth, not only over several lifetimes but until both attain liberation, that when one falls behind the other must wait. but not aware of any scriptural source.

This question is similar to: Is there a concept of soul mate in Hinduism?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@SwamiVishwananda - If a Jiva becomes liberated while living, it is free to go anywhere after exiting the body being a free spirit. If it decides to stay to liberate other jivas, it'll be its choice. Pranams.

The concept of soulmates in Hinduism is intriguing and somewhat complex.
While traditional scriptures don’t explicitly mention "soulmates," the idea of deep, karmic connections between souls is certainly present. In Vedic astrology, it’s believed that individuals can be connected across multiple lifetimes, potentially reuniting as spouses or significant partners.
While we may have profound bonds with certain people, the ultimate connection is with the divine rather than a single perfect partner. Relationships are seen as opportunities for growth and learning, rather than just romantic fulfillment.
If you’re exploring karmic connections these can help you along the way:
Self-Reflection and meditation: Think about recurring patterns in your relationships, connect with your inner self - your past and present. What lessons can you learn from them?
Heal Past Wounds: any unresolved issues from previous relationships, heal yourself to free yourself from their influence. Seek therapy or astrological guidance if needed.
Embrace Growth: View each relationship as a chance to grow and learn, making them incredibly fulfilling.
